# Why does FromData return an empty object ehrn I console.log it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this input file that I'm trying to upload to a database. Everything works fine if I write the post request on the client side, but I want to make the post request on the server route which means I have to take the FormData and send it to the backend api.
When I console.log(FormData) it always returns an Empty object {}.

```
formData.append("file", input.img);
formData.append("upload_preset", "blogville");
console.log(formData)
// result = {}
```

any way around this?